# Trying to make a simple client sided chatbox; giving me a cout problem

Tags: visual-c++

I am almost completely new to c++ and have been trying to create a simple client sided chat box just to test but have come across the problem that the output of my cin gives only the first letter of the name given.

~ Jayden

I've tried declaring the "userName" as a bool, int and char however two of these give the cout a number as the outcome. I have youtubed this but it seems like it's a noob problem so no one has an answer from what I've seen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int userName;
bool nameSuccess = false;
cout << "Welcome to ChatBox v1.43" << endl;
cout << "========================" << endl;
do {
    cout << "Enter a username: ";
    cin >> userName;
    cout << "You will now be known as ";
    cout << userName;
    nameSuccess = true;
} while (!nameSuccess);
system("pause");
cin.ignore();
cin.clear();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

The console should output the user name in this format : "You will now be known as (userName)"

Comment: Please check the code line "int userName;". I suppose, variable type should be different then "int".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int userName;
```

This should be.

```
string userName;
```

As a name is a string, not an integer.
The type of a variable is super important in C++. So you should definitely take the time and look up what `int`, `char`, `bool` mean. Once you have done that you will see why none of them work for a name.

Comment: Omg I am so silly haha thanks so much helped a lot <3 I feel stupid now haha

Comment: @JaydenCheats Glad I could help, please accept my answer for reputation sake.